# Advertising policy?

Tags: discussion

I've noticed several answers that appear to only (just!) try to stay on topic while advertising a product.  For example:

[This answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/66300/47496) (7 hours ago) on [this post](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/12570/47496) (from March 2012)
[This answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/66300/47496) (also 7 hours ago) on [this post](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/57627/47496) (from May this year)

Further evidence is that this [user](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/54579/user3981377) signed up 7 hours ago, and has had no action before or after these answers were posted (apart from the exact same behaviour over on SO).

What should I do with these types of posts?  On the surface it often doesn't look like pure spam/advertising, but is quite obvious once you've looked at the user's other answers/surrounding behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

That user has been wiped a couple of times. And I've just wiped them again. Best plan is just to flag them as spam - they come up at the top of the mod queue.

I know non-mods may not be able to see the previous ones (actually, 10k-ers probably can) but go by behaviour. If it looks like a spammer flag it and mods will deal with it (usually signing up and posting a link only answer is a good indicator).

If they are network-wide, we speak to other mods, or SE devs and they take wider action.